# JPA Hibernate Search

Tags: hibernate, input, parameters, hibernate-search

```
java.sql.SQLException: JZ0SA: Prepared Statement: Input parameter not set, index: 0.
```

I am trying to load a table from Sybase IQ using JPA 
I need this to do a text based look up. The plan is to pass the below mentioned 
Ids as a part of the search String and get the object as a value. For that to happen I am relying on the hibernate search to work moving ahead 
I am able to connect with the db and have the below model classes:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(CfgStaticLookupPrimaryKey.class)
@Table(name = "LookupTb")
@Indexed
public class LookupTbModel implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7298273381415615983L;

    @Embedded
    private LookupPrimaryKey lookupPrimaryKey;

    @Field
    private String cfgCategory;

    @Field
    private String cfgType;

    @Id
    @Field(index = Index.TOKENIZED, store = Store.YES)
    @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String cfgKey1;

    @Id
    @Field(index = Index.TOKENIZED, store = Store.YES)
    @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String cfgKey2;

    @Id
    @Field(index = Index.TOKENIZED, store = Store.YES)
    @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String cfgKey3;
```

and below dependent table

```
@Embeddable
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class LookupPrimaryKey implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2496396080324641200L;

    @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String cfgKey1;

    @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String cfgKey2;

    @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String cfgKey3;
```

After creating the EntityManager when I try to create the index 
using the below method

```
getFullTextEntityManager().createIndexer(LookupTbModel.class).startAndWait();
```

I am getting the below error

```
Error while executing the junit

    144556 DEBUG            JDBCExceptionReporter [Hibernate Search: entityloader-1]: could not execute query [select this_.cfgKey1 as cfgKey1_0_0_, this_.cfgKey2 as cfgKey2_0_0_, this_.cfgKey3 as cfgKey3_0_0_, this_.cfgCategory as cfgCateg4_0_0_, this_.cfgComments as cfgComme5_0_0_, this_.cfgKey4 as cfgKey6_0_0_, this_.cfgKey5 as cfgKey7_0_0_, this_.cfgType as cfgType0_0_, this_.cfgValue1 as cfgValue9_0_0_, this_.cfgValue2 as cfgValue10_0_0_, this_.cfgValue3 as cfgValue11_0_0_, this_.cfgValue4 as cfgValue12_0_0_, this_.cfgValue5 as cfgValue13_0_0_ from StaticLookupTb this_ where  (  ( this_.cfgKey1 = ? and this_.cfgKey2 = ? and this_.cfgKey3= ? ) or  ( this_.cfgKey1 = ? and this_.cfgKey2 = ? and this_.cfgKey3= ? ) or  ( this_.cfgKey1 = ? and this_.cfgKey2 = ? and this_.cfgKey3= ? ) or  ( this_.cfgKey1 = ? and this_.cfgKey2 = ? and this_.cfgKey3= ? ) or  ( this_.cfgKey1 = ? and this_.cfgKey2 = ? and this_.cfgKey3= ? ) or  ( this_.cfgKey1 = ? and this_.cfgKey2 = ? and this_.cfgKey3= ? ) or  ( this_.cfgKey1 = ? and this_.cfgKey2 = ? and this_.cfgKey3= ? ) or  ( this_.cfgKey1 = ? and this_.cfgKey2 = ? and this_.cfgKey3= ? ) or  ( this_.cfgKey1 = ? and this_.cfgKey2 = ? and this_.cfgKey3= ? ) or  ( this_.cfgKey1 = ? and this_.cfgKey2 = ? and this_.cfgKey3= ? )  ) ]
    java.sql.SQLException: JZ0SA: Prepared Statement: Input parameter not set, index: 0.
        at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybConnection.getAllExceptions(Unknown Source)
        at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybStatement.handleSQLE(Unknown Source)
```

I have not idea why this is happening and how to fix it any help would be appreciated.   I just want the indexer to work and index the table so that I can do look up based on the parameters provided.